# Need a rest call from java

Tags: java, api, rest, restful-authentication, restful-architecture

I am making a call to an API as a client. I ma using java to do this. I just need a response for now. I will convert the output later. 
My code is as follows:

```
String data = "User=admin&Password=1234&Authorization=basic&Keyword=nana";
URL url;
try {
    url = new URL("http://119.235.102.65/library/index.php/API/Search/basic");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

        OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
        wr.write(data);
        wr.flush();

    int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("Response code: " + responseCode);

        boolean isSuccesResponse = responseCode < 400;

        InputStream responseStream = isSuccesResponse ? conn.getInputStream() : conn.getErrorStream();

        wr.close();
         } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I am getting error code 401.

```
my url is : http://119.235.102.65/library/index.php/API/Search/basic
my username is : admin
my password is : 1234
```

Also iam going to search for a keyword from the database, which is nana. 
    keyword = nana.

Comment: yes. it needs authorization.

Comment: In your code sample, you did not send your credentials as part of your request. These likely need to be sent as headers or request parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I tried your rest api using POSTMAN rest client for Google Chrome and you have error:

don't use `Keyword=nana`

use: `keyword=nana`

The answer will be:

```
{
    "responsecode": 0,
    "responsemessage": "Success",
    "result": [
        {
            "BOOKID": "1",
            "BOOKTITLE": "Nana in the City",
            "BOOKCATALOGNUMBER": "abc 123",
            "BOOKDESCRIPTION": "In this magical picture book, a young boy spends an overnight visit with his nana and is frightened to find that the city where she lives is filled with noise and crowds and scary things. But then Nana makes him a special cape to help him be brave, and soon the everyday sights, sounds, and smells of the city are not scary—but wonderful. The succinct text is paired with watercolor illustrations that capture all the vitality, energy, and beauty of the city.",
            "PUBLISHERNAME": "Clarion Books",
            "PUBLISHERCITY": "New York",
            "TOTALCOPIES": "2",
            "AVAILABLECOPIES": "1",
            "LOANEDCOPIES": "1",
            "AUTHOR": [
                {
                    "AUTHORFNAME": "Lauren",
                    "AUTHORMNAME": null,
                    "AUTHORLNAME": "Castilo"
                }
            ],
            "BOOKCOPIES": [
                {
                    "REFERENCENUMBER": "123456",
                    "COPYNUMBER": "1",
                    "ISBN": "978-0544104433",
                    "EDITION": "1",
                    "PUBLICATIONYEAR": "2014",
                    "LOANEDSTATUS": "1"
                },
                {
                    "REFERENCENUMBER": "1234567",
                    "
...
...
```

[Image](http://prntscr.com/86ucc2)